# passing arguments into the reverse in get_success_url will return a list

Tags: django, django-views

I try passing an arg into the `reverse` function, but django reads the argument as a list of individual letters.

For example, if I override it like this:

```
def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        return reverse('profile:detail', args=self.kwargs['username'])
```

if the `username` on the `detail` page was "peter", I'll receive an error that says:
`Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('p', 'e', 't', 'e', 'r')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile/(?P<username>[\\w.@+-]+)/$']`

How do I override it while passing an argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass iterable type,  try this:

```
return reverse('profile:detail', args=[self.kwargs['username']] )
```

This will convert args to list.

Comment: Happen to know why it comes through as a list in the first place?

Comment: @Homer dnango expecting list,  snd when received string, automaically convert it to list. And since string is iterable, new list's items are chars.

Comment: @Homer in other words django expecting iterable and sinse string is iterable it iterate throug it and split to chars.